# Where could I find scipy interior point method code of implementation?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I'm looking for the code of sciPy's interior point-method..
On their github https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/optimize
I can just find code for the simplex method.

Does anyone know where I could find detailled code of the other implementations?

Comment: You could grab a debugger and step through the code, until you hit the function that contains the implementation (or possibly hit the call to C or Fortran code with the relevant implementation).

Comment: Isn't this it: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/701ffcc8a6f04509d115aac5e5681c538b5265a2/scipy/optimize/_linprog_ip.py#L821

Comment: yeah I think this should be what I was looking for...huge thanks! do you know if it is possible to warmstart scipys simplex algorithm by any chance?